# Android Room Persistent Library - sql query working on mysql but not in Room

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, android-room

I am trying to build conversations from messages, mid is message id, tid is thread id.

mid and tid are strings and time is long.

I have following query for the work, it works fine on mysql ( Ubuntu ) but when I copy it to @Query parameter for Room, it just selects all messages.

`select * from messages as a inner join (select tid, max(time) as time from messages group by tid) as b on a.tid = b.tid and a.time = b.time`

[image: This is the result i am expecting.]

The image shows the result, I am expecting in android.